# Junit and Java classpath woes - OS X

Tags: java, macos, junit, classpath

I'm trying to run the sample tests that come with junit4.7 and having some difficulty.

`java` is respecting my `CLASSPATH`:

```
me@dinosaurhunter ~/Desktop> export CLASSPATH=
me@dinosaurhunter ~/Desktop> echo $CLASSPATH

me@dinosaurhunter ~/Desktop> java junit.textui.TestRunner junit.samples.AllTests
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: junit/textui/TestRunner
me@dinosaurhunter ~/Desktop> source /etc/profile 
me@dinosaurhunter ~/Desktop> echo $CLASSPATH
:/Library/Java/Extensions/junit/:/Library/Java/Extensions/junit/junit.jar
me@dinosaurhunter ~/Desktop> java junit.textui.TestRunner junit.samples.AllTests
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: junit/framework/Test
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:164)
    at junit.runner.BaseTestRunner.loadSuiteClass(BaseTestRunner.java:207)
    at junit.runner.BaseTestRunner.getTest(BaseTestRunner.java:100)
    at junit.textui.TestRunner.start(TestRunner.java:179)
    at junit.textui.TestRunner.main(TestRunner.java:138)
```

but as you can see, it's unable to find `junit/framework/Test`... I looked in the `/Library/Java/Extensions/junit/junit.jar` and it is included, though.

`/Library/Java/Extensions/junit/junit.jar` is a symlink. Is that okay?

Comment: what happens if you add a -classpath var to the commandline and specify the jar directly?

Comment: with -cp and an unset $CLASSPATH I get the same results, even without using the symlink.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try putting the junit JAR file directly into the Extensions directory instead of creating a subdirectory for it.  I just copied the junit-4.6.jar into the /Library/Java/Extenstions directory and executed the TestRunner class with no issues

```
% java junit.textui.TestRunner
Usage: TestRunner [-wait] testCaseName, where name is the name of the TestCase class
```

Deleting the library from the Extensions directory results in the expected exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: junit/textui/TestRunner
```

Answer (score 5):

Ok, I just downloaded JUnit 4.7, unpacked the zip file, changed directory into the folder and ran the following command successfully:

```
$ java -cp .:junit-4.7.jar junit.textui.TestRunner junit.samples.AllTests 
.........................................
.........................................
.........................................
.......
Time: 3.255

OK (130 tests)
```

That was on OSX.

I think in your example, your classpath is a little messed up. Try this:

```
.:/Library/Java/Extensions/junit:/Library/Java/Extensions/junit/junit.jar
```

See the differences? I added the `.` (current directory) and I removed the trailing slash from the junit directory.

UPDATE: I just tested with a symlink and that appears to work too:

```
$ ln -s junit-4.7.jar junit.jar
$ java -cp .:junit.jar junit.textui.TestRunner junit.samples.AllTests 
.........................................
.........................................
.........................................
.......
Time: 2.569

OK (130 tests)
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you build the JAR yourself? This looks like the JAR is built without annotation.

If you compile the JUnit with

```
  javac -proc none ...
```

You will get this error.

Answer (score 0):

Some things to investigate:

Is the junit.jar file in the location you specify, and is it readable?
Is CLASSPATH exported by /etc/profile?
Does it work when you set "-cp $CLASSPATH" instead on the command line?
Try removing the leading colon in the classpath -- should not be there.

Comment: Yes, the junit.jar exists there with permissions 755. CLASSPATH is exported by /etc/profile. Unsetting CLASSPATH and using -cp gives me the same results. The leading colon doesn't seem to affect it either.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible that using a symlink is causing your problem. Trying adding the jar that symlink is pointing to and try again.

However looking at the [java man page for mac os x](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/java.1.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/1/java) there doesn't seem to be such a restriction.

Comment: I did it without the symlink and I'm still getting the exact same issue.